# What is the convention that follows `http_parser`?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using the module [http-parser](https://github.com/nodejs/http-parser) to parse responses from a server and the thing is that I'm receiving the error `HPE_INVALID_HEDER_TOKE` and as far as I know the reason is because the server is returning me bad headers. So I make a test to`http-parser` and effectively the headers that is returning me the server is wrong.

My question is: what is the key/value convention that is followed by the `http-parser` so I could know what is the server doing wrong?